# How to get all owl:intersectionOf axioms using OWL API in Java?

Tags: java, owl, owl-api

I have the following in the owl ontology file and I parse it with OWL API in Java. I want to retrieve the `owl:intersectionOf` classes.

```
 <owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="#P">
    <rdfs:domain>
        <owl:Restriction>
            <owl:onProperty rdf:resource="#R"/>
            <owl:someValuesFrom>
                <owl:intersectionOf>
                    <owl:Class rdf:about="#C"/>
                    <owl:Class rdf:about="#D"/>
                </owl:intersectionOf>
            </owl:someValuesFrom>
        </owl:Restriction>
    </rdfs:domain>
 </owl:ObjectProperty>
```

I use the following:

```
Object[] domains= EntitySearcher.getDomains(owlProperty, owlOntology).toArray();
for(Object domain : domainArr) {
    System.out.println(domain.toString());
}
```

and it return this:

```
ObjectSomeValuesFrom(<http://www.someValue.com.owl#R> <http://www.someValue.com.owl/error#Error1>)
```

The owl:intersectionOf is returned as Error1.

1. How to fix this?
2. How to get all owl:intersectionOf axioms using OWL API?

Comment: if that happens, then it already occurs in the parsing step. So you have to fix your ontology before loading it via OWL API

Comment: and for getting the restriction classes, you have to use a http://owlcs.github.io/owlapi/apidocs_5/org/semanticweb/owlapi/model/OWLClassExpressionVisitorEx.html as OWL class expressions can be arbitrary deeply nested.

Comment: Error1 is a marker for badly structured expressions, in this case the restriction tag is missing a type. Did you create the ontology by hand or via a tool?

Comment: I created it by hand

Comment: What is the mistake in the bad in this structure? how to fix it?